# Get_Multi vs. query in NDB. I.e. reads versus cache

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

so in my app i have a graph search problem (see my previous questions).  One of the annoying parts of the algorithm i use is that I have to read in my entire ndb database to memory (about 5500 entities, 1mb in size in the datastore statistics). things work ok with a

```
nodeconns=JumpAlt.query().fetch(6000)
```

but i would prefer it if the cache were checked first... doing so with

```
nodeconns=ndb.get_multi(JumpAlt.query().fetch(keys_only=True))
```

works offline but generates the following error online:
"Exceeded soft private memory limit with 172.891 MB"

speedwise the normal query is fine but i am a bit concerned that every user generating 5500 reads from the datastore is gonna eat into my quota quite quickly :)

So, my question is, (1) is such a large memory overhead for get_multi normal? (2) is it stupid to read in the entire database for each user anyway?

Comment: You have not really asked a question.  I would suggest you re-state in terms of a specific question, or you will get lot's of -1's and have the question closed very quickly.

Comment: IN general your strategy won't scale, and it will cost you a lot (ie upgrading to bigger instances with more memory)

Comment: Thanks tim, I have clarified the question a little.  I was hoping that finding an efficient way to keep the whole database in cache would help me, but i was surprised at the large memory cost of doing so.  so i guess i need to rewrite my algorithm and see if its better if just queries the data it needs as it goes along (probably this is  O(5500) anyway, so maybe not)

Comment: Alright, so I altered the Djikstra's algorithm to use get_by_id() on individual nodes as it searches the graph (before i was loading the whole graph and constructing a dictionary object).  upside: less data reading operations, downside, loss in performance (server times out most of the time).   Hehe, I honestly have no idea what i am doing :)  will the performance get better as more of the database sits in cache? should i look at threading or deferring the graph search if it times out?

Comment: One last note, in the end I followed your advice Tim and just ran on a larger memory instance. sticking with get_multi and doing that seems like the best option.  the average memory use actually drops to 50mb, and the datastore reads are minimal, so it seems like get_multi wins overall!  I guess I can close this question